# Style wordpress protected posts

Tags: wordpress, passwords

Is there a way to style password protected posts in Wordpress? Plus I can only seem to protect the  and not any custom fields outside of this.

***Edit*** – Trying to avoid using a plugin if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean styling the password protected posts on the front-end.

**a) CSS:**

If your theme is using the `post_class()` function, like:

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>...</article>
```

then it will generate:

```
<article class="... post-password-required ...">...</article>
```

for the password protected posts.

So you can simply target these posts with:

```
.post-password-required {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

in your stylesheet.

**b) Form:**

*i)* If you want to add text to your password form, you can use the following:

```
add_action( 'the_password_form', 'rob_the_password_form' );
function rob_the_password_form( $output )
{
    $before = ' Before ';  // Modify this to your needs!
    $after  = ' After ';   // Modify this to your needs!
    return $before . $output . $after;
}
```

*ii)* If you want to modify the HTML form directly, you can override it with:

```
add_filter( 'the_password_form', 'rob_override_the_password_form' );
function rob_override_the_password_form( $form = '' ) {
    global $post;
    $label = 'pwbox-'.( empty( $post->ID ) ? rand() : $post->ID );
    $form = '<form action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=postpass', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post">
    ' . __( "To view this protected post, enter the password below:" ) . '
    <label for="' . $label . '">' . __( "Password:" ) . ' </label><input name="post_password" id="' . $label . '" type="password" size="20" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="' . esc_attr__( "Submit" ) . '" />
    </form>
    ';
    return $form;
}
```

where this is based on the example from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Password_Protection#Password_Form_Text). It uses the same form as the default one.

**c) Title:**

To change the default *Protected:* title prefix, you can use:

```
add_filter( 'protected_title_format', 'rob_protected_title_format' );
function rob_protected_title_format( $format )
{
    $format = __( ' Members only! %s ' ); // Modify this to your needs!
    return $format;
}
```

Hopefully this will help you to style your protected posts.

Comment: Can't seem to get the functions working correctly, getting the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in .../wp-content/themes/2015/functions.php on line 4

Comment: I assumed you got PHP >= 5.3 ... let me update it for older versions ... please check now

Comment: Its getting there. Not getting the error on the post page but on another page getting this error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../beta/wp-content/themes/2015/functions.php:3) in /.../beta/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1178

Comment: I guess you have added some blank lines into your functions.php file, try to remove them and take a backup of the file before editing it.

Comment: Ah great! Didn't realise it was so sensitive to the extra lines. All working now, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Protected Post Personalizer plugin for doing the trick https://wordpress.org/plugins/protected-post-personalizer/

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was trying to avoid a plugin if possible.

Comment: Its getting there. Not getting the error on the post page but on another page getting this error:  
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at .../beta/wp-content/themes/2015/functions.php:3) in /.../beta/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1178